# Suggestions needed ... name our chat room?

Tags: discussion, suggestions

[Cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) has **The Frying Pan**.

[Philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/) has **Schrodinger's Discussion**

So it seems the other stacks have super duper names for their chat rooms, while currently our chat is branded **Gardening & Landscaping Discussion**.

So, what's your suggestion? One suggestion per answer, please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Idea 2:

**Garden Shed or Potting Shed or The Shed** is where gardeners disappear to for a cup of tea (or something a little stronger).

Comment: this appears to be the top voted answer after leaving the question open for a week

Answer (score 5):

**The Green Room**, maybe - trips off the tongue (only three syllables), a touch whimsical and, in the context of our site, conjures up the image of a club where gardeners might discuss their activities.

Answer (score 3):

This is just my opinion but why not the **"Gardening Chat Room"**?

I'm not entirely sure why sites want to come up with cutesy names. It gives everyone a bit of a chuckle, but then you've completely obfuscated what you room is about. When I look through the chat room listings, I never know what these rooms are for. *"Meh, if you don't want to make it easy for me, why bother?"*

It seems like a lost opportunity to attract an audience. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: i take your point, but i think the appeal is in being able to mark chat out as an area that's a bit less *utilitarian* than the rest of the site. playfulness is carefully excised from the main site (rightly so). chat is where a bit of silliness is allowed to, er, blossom.

Comment: or perhaps not. i hadn't realised the plan wouldn't have your (or your team's) endorsement.

Comment: @Tea Drinker: My opinion is not the position nor policy of the team. I'm just trying to weigh the "silly factor" vs the clarity of a utilitarian name. Other sites seem to prefer your approach. It's just my opinion. I would support whatever name this community chooses for their chat room. Really.

Answer (score 2):

Idea 1:

**Garden Fence** is where gardening neighbours congregate to shoot the breeze over the garden fence.

Answer (score 2):

Idea 3:

**The Patio or The Terrace or The Courtyard** is where people congregate in the garden to socialise.

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of Robert's answer -- **"The Garden"** provides a name that has an obvious purpose, while being less brute-force than "Gardening & Landscaping Discussion".

Answer (score -3):

**The Compost Heap** would be a good name, as it reflects both gardening and to a lesser extent landscaping and to a lesser extent computer science (which isn't particularly necessary).

Answer (score -4):

Idea 4:

**Oasis** somewhere to go and relax.